# How to convert datetime in SQL to Scala data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am importing some data from an MS SQL table to Scala program. MS SQL table has around 20 fields so I am making a class to load those rows in my Scala program.

1. In MS SQL there is one column whose data type is datetime, how do I store this kind of data type in my Scala program, I don't think Scala has this data type?
2. There is one more column Price (numeric(14,4),not null) whose data type is numeric in MS SQL. How do I store these kind of values in MS SQL?

Comment: Hi there Maddy. You can use DateTime, Scala uses a lot of Java libraries and so on underneath. So you can definitely use DateTine. I'd recommend looking at the DateFormatter too

Comment: And for the Price column, if it has decimals you should be able to use Double or Long in Scala.

Comment: So for datetime, I need to import from java library  as Scala doesn't have this data type. And it will be good, if you can give an example by writing few lines of Code.

Comment: import org.joda.time._  should work and to get the specific code, I'd need to see what your code is returning. But you should be able to parse it into DateTime. DateTime.parse(yourtime), of course the formatting and so on depends.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful as I'm new to Scala.

Comment: No problems Maddy! Do you mind if I put as an answer to get higher reputation on the site? Of course if you have any more question you can always message me. But I'd say overall, anything you can do/use in Java, usually works in Scala. :)

Comment: You are Welcome to put as answer. :)

Comment: You still have to pick it for me to get any points though :x

Comment: I  got this from Stackoverflow : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you can use DateTime, Scala uses a lot of Java libraries and so on underneath. So you can definitely use DateTine. I'd recommend looking at the DateFormatter too.

The library and more info:
import org.joda.time._ 
https://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html

You should be able to parse it into DateTime. DateTime.parse(yourtime), of course the formatting and so on depends. Like mentioned, DateFormatter helps a lot with this.

And for the Price column, if it has decimals you should be able to use Double or Long in Scala.